# Hide status bar in iphone/ipad apps

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an application for iPhone iPad.

My test iPhone (v4) is on iOS 6.
My test iPad is on iOS 7.

I'd like to remove both statuses bar from the whole application.

Here's what I've tried :

In info.plist, I've set `Status bar is initially hidden` to `YES` and `View controller based status bar` to `NO`

This didn't work.

So I've set `View controller based status bar` to `YES` and in my main view controller I've added :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Though this function never gets called.

In this same controller I've added this to `loadview`:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

This worked for the iPhone, but the bar still shows up on iPad.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

I also have checked "Hide during application launch" in project settings.

**EDIT :**

Here are two screenshots of my project settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkUSF.jpg

As you can see I've tried the answers of the question you voted this as a duplicate to.

If I'm not doing it wrong, thanks for voting to re-open this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to set deployment infos to universal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two things to have the status bar hidden throughout whole app in all iOS versions

1. In info.plist `View controller based status bar` set to `NO` . (For iOS 7)
2. In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` add  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` or simply `[app setStatusBarHidden:YES]`

Now you can optionally set `Status bar is initially hidden` to `YES` also to hide status bar when app launches.

Also if you dont want status bar to be hidden throughout the app.
 remove `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]`

and override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your ViewControllers and return YES or NO

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is important if you want to hide the status bar throughout the app.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `Status bar is initially hidden to YES`, it will work fine.

Anyways Have you tried below methods?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];

        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{        
    return YES;
}

- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden
{
    return nil;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: After this the bar still show up on iPad. Note that I've defined `Status bar initially hidden` to `YES` (as mentioned in my OP)

Answer (score 0):

Click xCode project/your target/General/Deployement Info, then check the "hide during application launch"